# Extending Observable with custom functionality

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

My situation: I have a datastore where I can get models that can be observed using RxJS Observables. The general type signature is

```
const foo = new Model({id: 123}, dataStore);
foo.asObservable().subscribe((v) => /* do stuff with values of this model */ );
```

the general notion is that treating data like observables helps in two ways: (a) when you've got a cold cache situation (like the browser's localStorage has some out-of-date data) but still want to display something while the actual data is being fetched, and (b) when you've got the proper data loaded already, but changes are made to it either locally or on the backend that need to propagate up. This works reasonably well so far.

The next-level problem is that models have relationships to other models (parents have many children, for example). As per usual in this, the I can do stuff like

```
foo.asObservable().subscribe(v => console.log(v.relationships.children))
```

and (ignore null errors here), I'd get [1, 2, 3] initially and then [1, 2, 3, 4] when 4 is added to the parent-child-relationship. With me so far?

The problem is that I often want to access these children, not as indices, but as observable models in their own right (so I can display the first names of all the members of a user community, for example, where both the community and all the members are data models). I'm currently doing this with a lot of boilerplate in my controller code, involving a lot of calls to `.combineLatest`.

What I want to do is define a custom operator for objects of this type so I can boilerplate it all together. Ideally it would look like:

```
foo.asObservable().inflateRelationship('members').subscribe(
  (v) => // v === [{name: 'steve'}, {name: 'gertude'} ...] etc
);
```

I actually have this partly working, but the problem is kicking off the actual chain. I'm following the [instructions for extending Observable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/operator-creation.md), creating a new CustomObservable class that implements `lift`, but my issue is that I can't use static Observable methods here, like Observable.merge(), to generate my initial observable in `Model.asObservable`.

My problem comes here:

```
const preload$ = Observable... 
  // create the "load from cache and backend observable"
const update$ = Observable ... 
  // create the "update after load when the storage updates observable" 

return new CustomObservable(context).merge(preload$, update$);
```

It's that last line that fails. I want to return this CustomObservable made from a merge operator on the two regular observable streams. I need to add the context to the constructor there, because that context contains references to the data stores needed to actually inflate the child models (without that, the stream of id arrays is kind of pointless).

So that's my specific problem: I've created an Observable operator that I want to add to CustomObservable as a class, so I can just use the downstream operators like normal, but I can't seem to properly get the whole chain kicked off.

Any pointers, even to existing projects that correctly (and non-trivially) extend the Observable class would be welcome. I tried digging into the source code, but I can't even figure that part out (it looks like the Observable class statics are added somewhere else, and it's super-unclear how at first glance, since nothing's defined in the [Observable class itself](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts)).

Comment: hmm, it seems as though I might be able to just do this more easily with `.let` and `.lift` to add the operator after the base observable is created but before I return it from `Model.asObservable()`

Comment: Yep. I'd read your question earlier and was about to comment that `let` might be what you are looking for. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38344020/6680611) explains `let`, if you've not used it before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those "write a really long question to stack overflow and figure out the answer shortly after you've posted it" sort of situations, but I figured I'd write up the answer just for posterity's sake.

Assuming you've followed the instructions to subclass Operator, what you do is

```
asObservable() {
  // do a bunch of stuff making different things
  return Observable.merge(one$, two$)
    .let(obs => new CustomObservable(context, obs);
```

and then in CustomObservable you have

```
class CustomObservable extends Observable {
  constructor(context, source) {
    super();
    this.source = source;
  }
  customOperator() {}
  lift(operator) {
    const obs = new CustomObservable(context, this);
    obs.operator = operator;
    return obs;
  }
}
```

and this lets me do

```
Model.asObservable()
.filter() // normal RxJs operator here
.customOperator() // yay
.map() // back to other RxJs operators
.subscribe(v => console.log(v)) // or whatever
```

so, yay. Now my angular models can look a lot more spare.

Comment: TSLint: `source is deprecated: This is an internal implementation detail, do not use. (deprecation)`

Comment: source: "@deprecated — Internal implementation detail, do not use directly. Will be made internal in v8."